# Mongoid 3.0.0: Query by "id" field, not "_id"

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

Is there an idiomatic way in Mongoid 3.0.0 to query a collection of documents using a non-unique field named `id` which is not the same as `_id`?

```
#<BltBasket _id: 52a16cd36cf462b442871709, id: 9334, ...>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me one good thing about mongoid is that you can define aliases.

So for your example I would see it as

```
field :_id, as: :uid,          type: String
field :id,  as: :a_funky_name, type: String
```

which will provide you with a

```
BltBasket.find_by( a_funky_name: :foo )
```

Excuse me if I understood your question the wrong way :-)

Comment: You understood and answered it perfectly. :) Thank you!